# jquery 'noty' plugin is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dreamweaver

when i try to alert the id after inside the first function which is just above
var ajax0 = false; it doesn't alert and the dialog box doesn't show at all even if i don't alert the id as it doesn't exist and it's inside document ready

```
$(document).on("click","a.del_cart",function(){
var id = $(this).attr("title");
noty({ text: 'product will be deleted',"modal":"true","layout":"center", buttons: [{type: 'button green', text: 'Ok', click: function() {
var ajax0 = false;
ajax0 = new XMLHttpRequest();
var qst0 = "?id="+id;
ajax0.open("POST","ajax/del_product.php"+qst0);
    noty({"text":"cancelled successfully.","layout":"center","type":"success","textAlign":"center","easing":"swing","animateOpen":{"height":"toggle"},"modal":"true","animateClose":{"height":"toggle"},"speed":"500","timeout":"2000","closable":true,"closeOnSelfClick":true});
    $(".cart").fadeOut(100,function(){
        display_cart();
        $(".cart").fadeIn(2000);
    });
ajax0.send(null);
 } }, {type: 'button pink',text: 'Cancel', click: function() { /**/ } }],closable: false,timeout: false });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
noty{"text":"", ..., "closeOnSelfClick":true};
```

Should be

```
noty({"text":"", ..., "closeOnSelfClick":true});
```

You are missing parentheses.

Comment: just copied and pasted from the website but still a problem look at this please (code updated above) thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should encase the noty object within parantheses. I think that is the problem.

edit: ninja'd ..

Comment: thanks but try to look at the updated code please